# Mail starts on every boot in macOS Catalina

Tags: mail.app, catalina

Every time I boot my iMac (19,1) into macOS Catalina, the Mail.app is open and waiting on the desktop.

The 'Open at Login' option appears to be bugged. Upon first start/restart of Mail, it's not set. If I click it, it gets a tick. From then on when I click it, it remains ticked and will not set to off.

How can I fix this and stop Mail opening on startup?

Answer (score 1):

Which 'Open at Login' option are you referring to specifically?

Things to check:

1. System Preferences > Users & Groups > [your user account] > Login Items tab

If mail has been added their remove it.

2. When you log out, restart or shutdown, you should get a "Reopen windows when logging back in" option.  Make sure that is either unchecked, or manually quit Mail before your log out, restart or shutdown.